# Trying to get a menu value before submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, popup

So I'm trying to get a popup box to show when a user rates an item but the value of the drop-down menu won't travel along with it. When I submit I would like it to grab the value and put it in the URL as a variable. Any ideas?

```
<form onsubmit="window.open('rateIt.php?rate=<?php echo **THE VALUE OF THE DROP-DOWN** ?>','popup','width=500,height=500,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0'); return false">
  <select name="rate" id="rate">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
  <input name="rateit" type="submit" value="Rate It"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply your own function for your form's submit event:

```
document.getElementById("formId").onsubmit = function(){
    var rateVal = this.rate.value;
    window.open('rateIt.php?rate=' + rateVal);
};
```

Just make sure you either put this script at the **bottom** of your page, or in your body's `onload` handler.  If you just put it in the `head` section, `getElementById` won't find your form, since the dom won't be ready yet.

**EDIT**

Just make sure you add `values` to these options:

```
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks a ton! I've been looking for how to do this for probably an hour.

Comment: The problem with that is IE 8 and below will return an empty string because the option elements don't have a value attribute. If the OP adds that (e.g. so each has a value attribute the same as the text), then all is well.

Comment: @Alex - RobG knows whereof he speaks.  Can you add value attributes to each of your option elements?

Comment: Also, `var rateVal = document.getElementById("rate").value;` can be just `this.rate.value;`

Comment: @RobG - thanks for the heads up - I would never have thought of that

Comment: @Alex - *you're* the OP -- original poster :)  If you add value attributes to your options like my edit shows, it should work in IE8

Comment: @Adam Rackis oh ya gottcha. I saw that right after I asked. Thanks again. I'm working on a project for school and that helped a ton.